# Comparing data in Salesforce and Pardot

Tags: python, api, salesforce, pardot

Is there anyway to do a one to one comparison between Pardot and Salesforce. I am aware that these two are synced, but I do not find the connected data very reliable. I am more interested in writing in a code in python by using Salesforce and Pardot API and do one to one comparison. Has anyone come across such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to write such code. You would need to be conscious of the limits both systems impost (governor limits of Salesforce, Pardot API record limits).

Another option for you is to check the Pardot field sync options for the mapping to see what is going on. If these are not set as you like, even the best script would not yield the results you are looking for and the data would just be overwritten.